# Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::$Auth (In laravel 7.30.4)

Tags: laravel, authentication, admin, laravel-7

Trying to make a multi-authentication system. The index page for the admin didn't open and the above error message occured.
[Admin Login Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBAuS.png)

[Web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi2MR.png)

[Admin Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7mlg.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZD4j.png)

For now I wanted to have two users in the system. The code for Auth.php has been mentioned below:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'madmin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'madmins',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],

    'madmins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Madmin::class,
    ],
],


'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],

    'madmins' => [
        'provider' => 'madmins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],
```

Comment: Please add actual code and not just images.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove the second Auth like that

```
if(Auth::guard('madmin')->attempt())
```

then continue your code

Comment: I did that and got the error message"Undefined method attempt"

Comment: can you show me auth.php file in config directory?

Comment: I have attached the auth.php file and I tried the above method but got error message as"Undefined method 'attempt'.intelephense(1013)"